# How to get the incoming data (login, password) from jQuery to ASP.NET MVC, then compare and return the answer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I`m quite new with jQuery and looking for advise. How to get data, from jQuery modal (login/password) box to controllers method, and compare with the data in the database and return a response?

There is my login model.

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Controller methods, where I probably have to get data from modal jQuery.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]    
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Here is the modal window:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="myBtn">Login</button>
```

```
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
        </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="confirmPassword"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
      <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
      <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

And jQuery code, where it have to get data from modal box, but it does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
```

});

```
$('#confirmPassword').on('click',
function (e) {
    var password = $('.confirmPassword').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Account/Login',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { "password": password },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
    });
}
```

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: You do not have any form control with `class="confirmPassword"` so `var password` would always be undefined. And it would make no sense to just send the password anyway (you would need to send the value of all form inputs). And `contentType: 'application/json',` makes no sense either (your not stringifying the data so remove it).

Comment: Can you elaborate on _but it does not work_ ? Overall, on first glance, your code looks pretty okay and complete. The one thing that is a mismatch though is in your ajax call you have the transport method as `GET` , but in your C# code you tagged your Login method with `[HttpPost]` .. You would need to change your ajax transport verb to post

Comment: And `return View()` in the POST method makes no sense. You do not do anything with the view you return (and in would need to be a partial view anyway). And `RedirectToLocal()` and `RedirectToAction()` can never work - its an ajax call and ajax never redirects.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke thanks for response, tell me please, where for example I can specify class="confirmPassword" and var password could be defined.

Comment: @mituw16 thank you, exactly this Get/Post I do not understand in jQuery, in controller I have two Login methods Get and Post, if understand correctly, the data from jQuery have to come to Get method Login, that is why in jQuery function I specify Get.

Comment: I agree users Mituw16 and StephenMuecke. Apart from that, the data you are sending doesn't match what the action method is expecting. You should be sending JSON.stringif({ "user": user, "password": password }) by POST. In the action method add [HttpPost], user and password need to be parameters for that method. You can't use model unless you send a model object. Otherwise this will get null raise an error on model.Email, etc. Also if you don't add a success function, then user will not know log in was successful.

Comment: Also in your Javascript, when you do `var password = $('.confirmPassword').val();` it should be `var password = $('#confirmPassword').val();` as *confirmPassword* is not a class but an id.

Comment: @derloopkat thanks, how can I specify "user": user, in the HTML form?

Comment: @OlegLarionov, I see there's a field for `usrname`, the one that says *"Enter email"*. Get the value using this code `$('#usrname').val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the HTML and see if it works...  Here are the things that I did to attempt to make it work.

- Added names on inputs (Name, Email, RememberMe) to match the ViewModel
- Added action (~/Account/Login) and method (post) on form tag
- Changed button type to submit

Hopefully this will help pass the model to the MVC controller.  Set a breakpoint in the first line of the controller Post login method and see if it hits it with Model filled out.

```html
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
      <form role="form" action="~/Account/Login" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
          <input name="Email" type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
          <input name="Password" type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password" >
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
        </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
      <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
      <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the data is transferred to the model, it remains to correct jQuery.